# Flutter Error: The getter 'iterator' was called on null

Tags: android, flutter, future

I'm trying to single output the product base by id. however i got an error Map is not a subtype of type iterable. I'm still new ang learning, i'm a bit stuck here.

here is my API, I think the error is coming from here. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
Future<List<Product>> fetchProduct(String productID) async{
String productPost = ApiUtil.productPost(productID);
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Accept' : 'application/json'
};
var response = await http.get(productPost, headers: headers);
List<Product> productpost = [];
if( response.statusCode == 200 ) {
  Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);
  for ( var item in body['data'] ){
    Product product = Product.fromJson(item);
    productpost.add(product);
  }
}
return productpost;
```

}

This is my model.

```
class Product {

     String id, name, description;

     Product(this.id, this.name, this.description);

     Product.fromJson( Map<String,dynamic> jsonObject ){
        this.id = jsonObject['id'].toString();
        this.name = jsonObject['name'];
        this.subname = jsonObject['description'];
     }
}
```

and this my detail class.

```
class ProductDetails extends StatefulWidget{

   final String productID;
   ProductDetails(this.productID);

   @override
   ProductDetailsState createState() => new ProductDetailsState();

   class ProductDetailsState extends State<ProductDetails> {

     ProductApi productapi = ProductApi();

     @override
     void initState() {
      super.initState();
     }

.... return Scaffold ...
Container(
   child: FutureBuilder(
      future:  productapi.fetchProduct(widget.productID),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

         if( snapshot.hasError ) {
            return Text ('NO DATA');
         }
         if( snapshot.hasData) {
            return _productDetail( snapshot.data );
         }
         return null;
      },
    )
  ) 

_productDetail( List<Product> product ){
   return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: product.length,
      itemBuilder: ( BuildContext context, int index ){
         return new Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
         child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
               Text(product[index].name, textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: 
               TextStyle(fontSize: 28, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
            ]
         )
      );
    }
  );
}
```

I'm trying to learn and understand by searching references online, but some issues I'm still noob to see whats wrong.

This is the error i got from the console

```html
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: iterator
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      ProductApi.fetchProduct (package:tampr/api/product_api.dart:61:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      ProductDetailsState.initState (package:tampr/pages/product_details.dart:26:16)
#3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4068:58)
#4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
#5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
#6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
#7      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5127:14)
#8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
#9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
#10  <…>
```

JSON Data

```
{"data":[{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Product Name",
   "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
   "productimage": "product_img.jpg",
   "logo": "logo_img.png",
   "user_id": 1,
   "created_at": "2019-11-18 05:25:49",
   "updated_at": "2019-11-18 05:25:49",
   "options": [
      {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "option name",
            "image": "optionimage.jpg",
            "pivot": {
                "product_id": 1,
                "option_id": 1
            }
        },
   ]
}]}
```

Comment: Hi! In which line is the error happening? Usually, it comes right below the error message.

Comment: In the API, i think in this part ---> Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body); ...

Comment: Please, add an example of your json

Comment: I added my JSON data sample

Comment: I tried your example and it works fine. Are you sure that you receive json of such a scheme from the server?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem when I removed the signs [ and ] from your json example
Make sure that an array of objects and not an object actually comes from the server with the data field

Comment: Hi Artrem, when i fetch all items like i have 5 items, i can display all the items, but when I choose to display only item by id i got that error.

Comment: Well, could you print the response body from the server and add the output here?

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your problem. I took your code starting from the json decode and json itself and am not getting any errors.

Comment: I updated my JSON, now I got new error : NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.

Comment: This part is returning null ---  for ( var item in body['data']){
          Product product = Product.fromJson(item);
          productpost.add(product);
      } --- helppp

Comment: this may mean that body ['data'] returns null. Maybe you should look at the body variable in the debugger.

Comment: I solve it. The issues is with my API where for loop is. I remove the for loop since i'm fetching product by ID.

Answer (score 1):

I also fetched the same problem, in my case it happens because of :

> Product product = Product.fromJson(item);
> [item] structure coming from Firestore doesn't match [fromJson] decoding structure
> or maybe one of them is null or typo error in the field naming.

My error was on flutter but this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i forgot to check Whether item in a list is null or not. Below code help me to recover from same error

```
  if (filterRestaurantList[index].category != null) {
  for (var category
  in filterRestaurantList[index].category) {
  if (category.categoryDetail != null) {                            
  categoryList.add(category.categoryDetail.categoryName);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issues with my API for loop. By removing it answer the problem. Since the getter is by productID it return only one item.

```
Future<List<Product>> fetchProduct(String productID) async{
   String productPost = ApiUtil.productPost(productID);
   Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Accept' : 'application/json'
   };
var response = await http.get(productPost, headers: headers);
List<Product> productpost = [];
if( response.statusCode == 200 ) {
Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);
   Product product = Product.fromJson(item);
   productpost.add(product);
}
}return productpost;
```